# how to change linker setting in MASM32

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, masm32

I am using **MASM32 editor in windows 7 (64 bit).** By default my linker is "Incremental Linker Version 5.12.8078" which is not linking my programs. I want to use this linker 
"Microsoft (R) Segmented Executable Linker  Version 5.60.339 Dec  5 1994". Please tell me how to change my **MASM32 setting** and make it the default linker

Comment: You find the desired linker under `\masm32\bin\link16.exe`. It will produce 16-bit MS-DOS executables. Those executables will not be executed in 64 bit Windows. Have you already installed a DOS-emulator (e.g. DOSBox)?

Comment: If you really want to use a different linker, you can create a project from the _code_ menu, and then modify _makeit.bat_ to use an alternate linker for that particular project.

Answer (score 2):

Load `\masm32\menus.ini` in an editor (you can use the MASM32 Editor).

Scroll down to

```
&Run Program,"{b}.exe"

[&Tools]
```

Insert two lines:

```
&Run Program,"{b}.exe"
-
Build 16-bit,cmd /C\masm32\bin\ml.exe /Bl"C:\masm32\bin\link16.exe" "{a}" & pause

[&Tools]
```

Save the file and restart MASM32 Editor.

Now you have under "Project" a new item "Build 16-bit".