# Errors in linking in masm32 sdk

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

Iv just downloaded masm32 sdk and visual masm ide. While running the program its showing errors something **UNDEFINED SYMBOL DGROUP**. I googled and found that iv to use 16-bit linker. Now Iv set the path for 16-bit linker too. But still Its showing the same errors.

Im adding the screenshot of Error as well as setting page of visual masm Ide.[image: setting page]
[image: error page]

Comment: You tried to build it as a "32-bit Windows Console Application". Close all projects and choose **File-New-16-bit MS-DOS EXE Application.**

Comment: done that... now im getting error - "LINK : fatal error L1093: D:\Visual.obj : object file not found"

Comment: Yeah, I've got the same problem. It disappeared when I closed Visual MASM and opened it again. Why is your Visual MASM on drive D:? Have you installed it there?

Comment: yes.. while installing on drive c:, it was showing error like- " WRITE operation of exe has failed"

Comment: im still getting the same error  :(

Comment: Something went wrong. What kind of operating system do you have, especially 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64)? Run `msinfo32`. Is there a compelling need to program 16-bit MSDOS instead of 32-bit Windows?

Comment: its 64-bit OS.. yes.. there is a university practical exams

Comment: is there any other alternative to visual masm where i can learn to program in  masm assembly language

Comment: I just successfully installed Visual MASM on Win10 64-bit without any changes to the installer. I recommend to uninstall Visual MASM and install it again. A 64-bit Windows cannot run a 16-bit program. Use [DosBOX](https://www.dosbox.com/) for it. An alternative is Qeditor from the MASM32 SDK you've already installed with a small modification: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34219981/3512216

Comment: tried on dosBOX.. its running properly now.. thank you :)

Comment: My detailed HowTo for MASM32 and QEDITOR. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43328941/3512216

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Good success on your further journey.